# PHP MySQL get the record for a particular user whose data is not submitted

Tags: mysql

I have an Android App which tracks the attendance of 5 users.I have used MySQL database to store the data. Also, I have used PHP to link the Android App to MySQL database.

What I want is to check if the user has submitted the attendance till 10AM in the morning everyday.And if the user has not submitted his/her attendance till 10AM, then the attendance for that particular user will be marked as "Missed" automatically in the database for that particular user for the day(a new row will be inserted with the username and "Attendance" column will be marked "Missed"). So, I was trying to set a cron job in phpMyAdmin which will run everyday at 10AM and run the query. The problem is I am not able to figure out how to get the user who has not submitted the data by 10 AM through MySQL query. Let's say we have 5 users: A, B, C, D and E. So, if A, B has submitted the data for the day and C, D, E has not submitted their attendance (there is no record for C, D, E till 10AM).So, how to filter out C, D, E and automatically insert a row in the table with "No Records" for C, D and E for that particular day?

I tried creating the cron job using the below query:

```
CREATE EVENT check_attendance 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 DAY_HOUR
```

And I tried the below query to get the count of records for a particular day:

```
SELECT IF((SELECT count(*) FROM attendance WHERE date = NOW()) = 0, true, false ) AS VALUE
```

But I don't know how to write the query which will filter the names of records which are not there in the database. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe Try To Create another column with a bool that gets refreshed each day and gets updated when the particular users marks his atendance (say to 1) and use that in your If loop
(If property in column is 1) then insert into your records

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Will try it and let you know if it works as expected. :)